# Postgres Dumping database with only some schemas

Tags: postgresql

I have a database called `supre` with the following schemas `cdu, beirario, lider, koch, public`, however I would like to dump the database with only the schemas `cdu, beirario, public`.

Following [postgres' documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-pgdump.html) I found the `-s` flag, however that states that it only dumps the schema and a pg_restore wouldn't work with only that.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-n` option:

```sh
pg_dump -n cdu -n beirario -n lider ... dbname
```